"A bit of background something"
(From A Terrible Kindness by Jo Browning Wroe, Part I, Aberfan, chapter 7)

The cold swill of air and the sudden blare of a lorry make him look up. It's the navy blue coat and the tall figure of the Salvation Army man who served him, striding in with a black box in both hands.
'Thought you might like a bit of background something,' he says. 'Batteries are fresh in and I've got more if they run out.'

(the black box is a transistor radio)
I take background something to be a compound noun, right? However, a postposed something could have a different meaning there.

What's the "black box"? If it needs batteries it could be a portable radio. If it's a box of photos then why are batteries needed? This extract needs context.

I thought you might be asking for the meaning but it appears you're really looking for a part of speech. Background music it's a noun phrase.

He just means You might like to be able to hear something in the background - such as this radio. Probably because the place is depressingly silent. He says "something" because perhaps all that's needed is the murmuring sound of low-level "talk radio", not background music that anyone might actually listen to.

(He's hardly likely to be offering a radio so the mortician can listen to a comedy show on the radio while surrounded by corpses.)

@FumbleFingers  How do you know for certain? I often have some music playing in the background when I'm doing something or working. Yes, it could be a DJ interviewing someone, or a radio talk show. But "background music" is well attested. P.S I didn't read the synopsis of the book.

@Mari-LouA: We know the context. This OP has asked several questions about the book. I assume there's one particular mortician at the centre of the narrative, even though I saw yesterday that 400 morticians arrived at Aberfan within 48 hours.

@FumbleFingers We know the context I don't. This is the first time I spent reading the OP's question(s) . I have other things to do than comment endlessly on people's posts. And why wouldn't background music be a possibility? It doesn't have to heavy metal or techno, it could be Sinatra singing "I've got you under my skin"  for we all know.  And the volume could be turned down.

@Mari-LouA: Sorry, perhaps I should have said I know the context. But I only know it from OP's same initial text From A Terrible Kindness ... Aberfan. Which I haven't read either - but I did find a reference yesterday to those 400 morticians, when checking to see what happened to all the bodies in the immediate aftermath.

"Background something" is a natural development from "background music" or "background conversation".  These are formed with "background" as a noun adjunct.
Clearly the Salvation army person is offering a radio so the mortician can listen to "something" while working, but doesn't want to judge what the mortician wants in the background:  News and talk, easy listening or classical.
Given the date, the mortician wouldn't have much choice: either news and talk on the "Home Service",  light or easy listening music on the Light Program, or classical music on the Third Programme.
